# MS Visual C++ Express. Unable to show double pointer contents in Autos or Watch

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have coded as below -

```
typedef struct x{
    int val;
    struct x *next;
}X;

typedef struct y{
    int num_x;
    X **ex;
}Y;

int main(void)
{
    int i, num_x, ex;
    Y *v;

    scanf("%d", &num_x);

    v = (Y *)malloc(sizeof(Y));
    v->num_x = num_x;

    v->ex = (X **)malloc(sizeof(X*) * num_x);

    for(i=0; i < v->num_x; i++)
    {
        v->ex[i] = (X*)malloc(sizeof(X));
        scanf("%d", &ex);
        v->ex[i]->val = ex;
        v->ex[i]->next = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is, I am unable to see the contents of v->ex[i] in either Autos or in Watch windows.

Also tried (struct x *)(v->ex[0]) in watch window for which it says "bad type cast" !!

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,
/MS

PS: I am using MS VC++ Express 2010 for some reasons and not able to use later versions on my PC